# Trying to understand how to use Exception Handling with my code

Tags: python

I'm reading in stock data from Yahoo associated with the "tickers" (stock codes) provided to me in a CSV file. However, some of the stock codes are actually not available on Yahoo, so I was wondering if there is a way to account for this in my code below via Exception Handling.

```
import pandas
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
import csv

f1=open('C:\Users\Username\Documents\Programming\Financialdata.csv') #Enter the location of the file
c1= csv.reader(f1)
tickers =[]
for row in c1:          #reading tickers from the csv file
    tickers.append(row)
    start=datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)
    end=datetime.datetime(2013,1,1)
    l=[]; m=[]; tickernew=[]
    i=0;j=0; k=0; z=[]
    for tick in tickers[0]:
        f=web.DataReader(tick,'yahoo', start,end)
        if len(f)==250:         #checking if the stock was traded for 250 days
            tickernew.append(tick)      #new ticker list to keep track of the new index number of tickers 
            k = k + 1               #k keeps track of the number of new tickers
            for i in range(0,len(f)-1):
                m.append(f['Adj Close'][i+1]/f['Adj Close'][i])    #calculating returns
```

Comment: Reading https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Your first step should be to look at the traceback you get when your program crashes because of the invalid input you mention.

Then, simply wrap the line of the code you're crashing on with a try/except. Good Python style encourages you to be specific about what type of exception you're handling. So, for example, if the crash is raising a "ValueException" you'll want to do this:

```
try:
  bad_line_of_code
except ValueException:
  handle_the_issue
```